# How to Split String into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I Have a table like below

```
 Property   Value

 Adapter    [00000007] Intel(R) 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection
 Adapter    [00000009] VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
 Adapter    [00000012] Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card
```

from above table i want to split values column string into two columns like below is:

```
String1        String2
[00000007]     Intel(R) 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection
[00000009]     VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
```

Any solution please.

Comment: So you don't want to split by white-spaces? Otherwise also these would be splitted: `Intel(R) 82567LM` etc. So what is the exact rule?

Comment: You just completely changed the question!

Comment: I want to split based on ']'

Comment: Your expected results showing only one column, can you show the other?

Comment: what do you have? what output do you want to get? at the moment it's not even clear where other values from string should go

Comment: You changed the structure from a string to table values again? In future try to get it right before updating the question multiple times. It will give those attempting to answer a better chance.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  substring(Value,charindex('[',Value,1),charindex(']',value,charindex('[',Value,1)-1)) as String1
  ,ltrim(rtrim(substring(Value,charindex(']',value)+1,len(value)))) as String2
from Table1
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ee6f/4)**

Answer (score 0):

**As the question has changed this is no longer relevant but may prove useful to others...**

This seems to work:

```
declare @value varchar(100) = '[00000007] Intel(R) 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection'

SELECT 
SUBSTRING(@value, 0, CHARINDEX(']', @value,0) + 1) firstPart,
LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@value, CHARINDEX(']', @value,0)+1, LEN(@value)))) secondPart
```

Comment: I seem to still get the correct value for what you suggested. Are you sure this fails? I'm positive it still works and produces a two column output with the correct values but i could be wrong..

Comment: With drawn because the person posting the comment just changed the question

Comment: I saw it, but am still sure mine would have worked based on his first version of the question. o well.

Answer (score 0):

If your case simple one will work:

```
select
    Property,
    substring(Value, 2, 8) as String1,
    -- or substring(Value, 1, 10) if you want [ and ]
    right(Value, len(Value) - 11) as String2
from Table1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ee6f/14)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more generic version to support for any number of characters before the first space (**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22563)**):

```
SELECT LEFT(@S, CHARINDEX(' ',@S)) String1,
       RIGHT (@S, LEN(@S) - CHARINDEX(' ',@S)) String2
```

Applying to your Table:

```
SELECT LEFT(Value, CHARINDEX(' ',Value)) String1,
       RIGHT (Value, LEN(Value) - CHARINDEX(' ',Value)) String2
FROM yourTable
```